# connect to MDX using something like SQLCMD

Tags: ssas, mdx, sqlcmd, analysisservices

I'm trying to run my query without the need to have SSMS open and running. Previously I've used this connecting to SQL server database via SQLMCD utility to run batches. However, this query I am now using is in MDX so I am not sure on how that translates for a connection to analysis server. This is what I've used in the past to execute the query:

```
  echo StartTimeStamp > "%~dp0\StartTimeStamp.txt"
  sqlcmd -S businesspublish -d revcube -G -i "%~dp0\Step 1 - modify query.mdx" -o "%~dp0\Step 3 - Query 
  results in CSV format.csv" -s"," -w 700 -I -t 28800 -h-1
  echo EndTimeStamp > "%~dp0\EndTimeStamp.txt"
 #set /p delExit=Press the ENTER key to exit...:
```

This was written by a former colleague and I'm trying to recycle it, to execute the query with the following details:

**ServerName: Businesspublish
Database:RevCube
Query file name: Step 1 - modify query.mdx
Step 3 - Query results in CSV format.csv**

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the ASCMD utility. The folloing link explain how you can use XMLA, MDX,DMX on cube

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms365187(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN